# How do the makefile and #include commands interact?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, makefile

It may sound obvious, but I can't get a clear idea of how to manage Makefiles and `#include` commands.

As I understand, [`#include`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html) is used to - as per its name - include library files by indicating their header (`.h`) filename. They can be in the program folder or in some standard library directories. The [makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) specifies, among other things, what files and packages have to be put together when compiling the executable.

Say I want to add a source file I made (`.c` and `.h`) to an already existing program. Do I have to both `#include` and add them to the makefile?

EDIT - additional question: if I put a source file in the makefile but forget to `#include` it, will I get an error or will it just not be used?

Comment: You seem to be mixing two different concepts. The makefile contains instructions on how to build an application, while source file includes header files for declarations they need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in general.

All `#include` does is include, i.e. literally paste in, the mentioned file. Since a header (`.h`) file typically only contains declarations, but not *definitions* (i.e. the actual function implementations) it's not enough.

That's why you typically must interact with the *linker*, often from the Makefile, to tell it which additional libraries to link your program with.

Both are needed, since:

- Trying to link a program that has the `#include`s but not the correct libraries will fail, with "unresolved symbol"-type errors.
- Trying to call functions in a library that you are linking with, but without the proper `#include`s will generate "undeclared symbol" warnings or errors.

Comment: Probably a good idea to include an explanation of the context confusion that @JoachimPileborg mentions in his comment on the OP in this answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have an existing program consisting of `main.c`, `foo.c`, `foo.h` and a makefile that builds the program. And suppose you want to add `bar.c` and `bar.h`.

Anything that needs bar code must tell the compiler where to find it. Otherwise if the `Foo` class has a `Bar` member, and `main()` calls `bar_transform()`, the compiler will scream that it doesn't know what you're talking about. So `foo.h` and `main.c` must each contain this line:

```
#include "bar.h"
```

(The pattern here is a little subtle. Notice that `foo.c` probably does *not* need this directive, because it has `#include "foo.h"`, and `foo.h` has `#include "bar.h"`. Also, there are cases in which it would be better to use **forward declaration** int `foo.h` and put the directive in `foo.c` instead. If you have trouble with this, we can help.)

Now the code is correct. We can compile it and produce `main.o`, `foo.o` and `bar.o`. We just have to link them correctly.

The makefile must contain *something* that tells Make what files to use when building the executable, perhaps like this:

```
app: main.o foo.o
    $(CC) $^ -o $@
```

If you try this after modifying the source files, Make will compile `main.o` and `foo.o` correctly, then try to link them, and the linker will scream that the `Bar` class is incomplete, and it can find no definition of `bar_transform()`.

To incorporate `bar` in the build, you need only add `bar.o` to that list of prerequisites:

```
app: main.o foo.o bar.o
    ...
```

There are other ways the makefile could specify the list, so if you have trouble, show us your makefile. Also, this doesn't address the problem of *dependency handling* (e.g. knowing that `foo.o` must be rebuilt if `bar.h` has changed); this is probably very easy to fix, but we have to see the makefile.